# ¿Obtener valor de datepicker en edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, datepicker

Trato de obtener datos de datepicker en un edittext tipo date, como podría lograr eso, este es el diseño XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android="http:// schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context=".DatePicker">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:inputType="Date"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dpResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

public class DatePicker extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText date;
    DatePicker datePicker;
    int year;
    int month;
    int dayOfMonth;
    Calendar calendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_picker);

        date = findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.dpresult);

        Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                datePicker = new DatePicker(DatePicker.this, new DatePicker.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Date.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola te sugiero agregues el código que que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Comment: Por el codigo donde ejecutas el evento `setOnClickListener` del calendario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tienes dos problemas, primeramente debes definir el listener a tu `DatePicker` que es en realidad `datePicker` (No `Date`):

```
datePicker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    new OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                     ...
                     ...
        }
    });
```

Ahora lo que deseas es que al seleccionar una fecha esta se vea reflejada en tu `EditText` que es la variable `date` (no `Date`):

```
datePicker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    new OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            date.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo utilizo este y me sale muy bien:

```
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Calendario">
    imagenGenerator= new ImageGenerator(this.getActivity());
    imagenGenerator.setIconSize(50, 50);
    imagenGenerator.setDateSize(30);
    imagenGenerator.setMonthSize(10);

    imagenGenerator.setDatePosition(42);
    imagenGenerator.setMonthPosition(14);

    imagenGenerator.setDateColor(Color.parseColor("#3c6eaf"));
    imagenGenerator.setMonthColor(Color.WHITE);

    imagenGenerator.setStorageToSDCard(true);

    FechaInv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int SelectedYear, int SelectedMonth, int SelectedDay) {
                            FechaInv.setText(SelectedDay + "-" + SelectedMonth + "-" + SelectedYear);
                            calendario.set(SelectedYear, SelectedMonth, SelectedDay);
                            GeneraIcono = imagenGenerator.generateDateImage(calendario, R.drawable.calendar);
                            DisplayImagen.setImageBitmap (GeneraIcono);
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);

                    mDatePicker.show ();
                }
            });
        }
    } );

    // </editor-fold>
```

---

Y te muestra la fecha en el texto y en una imagen también... espero te sirva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]